# C++ Ambiguity of default constructor and something else. What is that something else?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm not sure what search terms I even need to use to find the answer to this question, so sorry if this is duplicated. Basically, Why does this compile?

```
struct A {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    A(){};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    A(const char*){};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    //const char* b = "what is going on?";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    A(b);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

But this does not?

```
struct A {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    A(){};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    A(const char*){};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    const char* b = "what is going on?";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    A(b);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}

test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8: error: conflicting declaration ‘A b’
test.cpp:7: error: ‘b’ has a previous declaration as ‘const char* b’
```

What feature of c++ is causing this ambiguity?
The main goal of this is to create an anonymous variable on the stack of type A. Similar to `A a(b);`, but not naming a.

Comment: There are no features of C causing ambiguity because it is not C code.

Comment: You have a `b` that is declared to be a `const char*`, then you declare another `b` as an `A`.  C++ does not allow this kind of variable shadowing in the same context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by an ambiguity in the C++ grammar. `A(b);` is parsed as a definition of `b`, an object of type `A`. This exact issue is described in [[stmt.ambig]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig).

To fix this, either use uniform initialization `A{b};` or surround it with parentheses to force it to be an expression instead of a declaration `(A(b));`. Either fix will allow your program to compile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you elaborate on what the ambiguity is? When would I want to declare b within parentheses this way? Why is that allowed as a declaration of b, I have never seen a declaration of this type used before. What key word could I use to find this declaration type within the c++ documentation?

Comment: @TheBat `()` are often used to group things in complex declarations (e.g. `int (*x)[N]`). but in your case they do nothing. Redundant `()` are probably allowed for convenience, or to keep the grammar more simple.

Comment: @TheBat Take a look at [stmt.ambig](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig) in the C++ standard.

Comment: @iz_ That is an amazing link, would you mind adding it your answer. Thanks for the awesome answer!